# How to import .e00 ArcGIS file in GeoPandas

Tags: python, gis, arcgis, geopandas, fiona

I'm trying to work with files from this site:

[NADP Website](ftp://ftp.epa.gov/castnet/tdep/grids/)

The files are `.e00` format.  When I attempt to open them with GeoPandas, I get a message that they appear to be compressed.

If I try using e00conv or AVCE00 to decompress the files, then open them with GeoPandas, I get a `FionaValueError`, that no dataset has been found.

Any suggestions for how I can get these files opened so I can put them in a format I can use?

I can load the decompressed file using `np.fromfile` but then all I have is a vector.

Comment: This might help: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/50121/adding-e00-data-into-qgis - Try installing e00conv and unpack your file, then open with geopandas and using AVCE00 driver. Depending on your environment, you might have to reinstall/rebuild some dependencies like gdal, Fiona, or geopandas itself.

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured this out.  In this instance, even though the .e00 format is not usually used to store raster file, these files are raster images.  They open fine with rasterio.